# App entry point - child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

The index action on my home controller is the entry point for my MVC 3 app. When I try to redirect to another view from within this action i'm getting the 'child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions' error on an Html.Action on my layout view. I'm not redirecting from a child view so can anyone explain why I'm getting this error. This only happens on the Index action of my home controller, any other action on any other controller, including the home controller works fine.

Home controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if ([some logic to lookup user] = 0)
            return View("UserNotFound");
        else
            return view();
    }
}
```

@Html.Action in layout:

```
@Html.Action("BuildMenu", "Menu", new { menu = @ViewBag.Menu })
```

Global.asax:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );

}
```

Menu controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult BuildMenu(string menu)
{
    var model = new ViewModels.MenuViewModel()
    {  
        Menu = menu,
        ShowCreateNew = BL.Permissions.CheckUserPermission(this.UserDetails.UserId, this.UserDetails.RoleId, BL.Common.permission_AddNewRisk),
        ShowAdmin = BL.Permissions.CheckUserPermission(this.UserDetails.UserId, this.UserDetails.RoleId, BL.Common.permission_AdminRights)
    };

    return PartialView("_Menu", model);
}
```

Comment: Can you please put the codes for `BuildMenu` and `UserNotFound` action methods?

Comment: The redirect should take place in the controller action itself, not in another action which is called from the view. Perhaps you want to use `RedirectToAction("UserNotFound")` in stead of rendering another view.

Comment: Hi, the view is just an empty view from the shared folders that displays an error message. The redirect does take place in the controller.

Comment: I've included the global.asax code to show how the index action is reached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a redirect inside the `BuildMenu` action of the `Menu` controller that only occurs when the user is not found?

That would cause this error as that is the child action referenced.

I have just tested exactly this and got the error:

`Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions`

If the `this.UserDetails` value is null, which based on the condition in the Home Index I assume is possible then that would cause an exception which is possibly being caught by a globally applied attribute which contains a redirect.

I tested this as well and got the same error.

Comment: @Wilky Do you have a global attribute applied that does a redirect on exceptions? Basically, there is something inside (or applied to) that action that is doing a redirect.

Comment: @Wilky Updated answer, hope it helps.

Comment: YES. My menu controller inherits from _controllerbase which does some error handling and a bloody redirect. How did I not see that. Thanks Richard!!